# json2typescript convert to type T

Tags: json, angular, type-conversion

I am using json2typescript in Angular and trying to create a general function to convert.  Right now I have it working with something like this:

```
  private ConvertBaseToRole(baseObject: any): Role {
    const jsonConvert: JsonConvert = new JsonConvert();
    jsonConvert.operationMode = Constants.ConverterMode;
    return jsonConvert.deserializeObject<Role>(baseObject, Role);
  }
```

This is fine but I have to create the same thing from every class I want to convert.  Instead I would like to do this as a generic function that can be used with any class:

```
export function ConvertBaseToObject<T>(baseObject: any): T {
  const jsonConvert: JsonConvert = new JsonConvert();
  jsonConvert.operationMode = Constants.ConverterMode;
  return jsonConvert.deserializeObject<T>(baseObject, T);
}
```

However it's giving me a compiler error `'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`.  How do I get the right value to use from the type `T` that is passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that Typescript generics only exist at compile time so you cannot use type-argument to instantiate types;

However your expected behavior could still be achieved as demonstrated below:

```js
export function ConvertBaseToObject<T>(baseObject: any, toType: { new(): T }): T {
  const jsonConvert: JsonConvert = new JsonConvert();
  jsonConvert.operationMode = Constants.ConverterMode;
  return jsonConvert.deserializeObject<T>(baseObject, toType);
}
```

Comment: Perfect thank you!  I was missing the idea of putting the definition as an argument.